# Set up application changes the controls position and sizes on Windows XP

Tags: winforms, setup-project

I created a setup project for a Windows Forms application it's working fine on Windows 7 and Windows 8. But when I installed a setup project in Windows XP, the positions of controls changed. How do I resolve this problem?

My application contains a panel of size fix to window size in Windows 7, but in Windows XP the panel size is increasing, and I am getting a horizontal scroll bar. I don't want a maximum size.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please elaborate your problem and tell us what have you tried yet.

Comment: My application contain a panel of size fix to window size in windows 7 but in windows xp panel size is increasing and i'm getting a horizontal scroll bar ,i dont want a maximum size